# OrderByChild() results is depending on case of the words

Tags: android, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, sql-order-by

Current firebase database is:

```
{
  "user_type" : {
     "number1" : {
      "name" : "Puneet",
    },
    "number2" : {
      "name" : "AMAN SINGH",
    },
     "number3" : {
      "name" : "harsha",
    }, 
    "number4" : {
      "name" : "abhishek",
    },
    "number5" : {
      "name" : "Satya",
    },
  }
}
```

I want to sort the list by name in ascending order. So for this code is :

```
 myRef.child("user_type").orderByChild("name");
```

But it is returning the result as:

```
{
  "admin" : {

    "number2" : {
      "name" : "AMAN SINGH",
    },
      "number1" : {
      "name" : "Puneet",
    },
     "number5" : {
      "name" : "Satya",
    },
      "number4" : {
      "name" : "abhishek",
    },
     "number3" : {
      "name" : "harsha",
    }

  }
}
```

But I am expecting the following order:

```
{
  "admin" : {

    "number2" : {
      "name" : "AMAN SINGH",
    },
       "number4" : {
      "name" : "abhishek",
    },
    "number3" : {
      "name" : "harsha",
    }
      "number1" : {
      "name" : "Puneet",
    },
     "number5" : {
      "name" : "Satya",
    }
  }
}
```

So instead of the current order, it is sorting first capital case letter words and then it is sorting small letter words and merging the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order you're seeing is exactly what I would expect.  This is because of the way strings naturally sort.  UTF-8 strings with ascii data sort according to the ascii byte value of each character.  As you can see from [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/), **all capital letters sort before all lowercase values**.  This explains the sort order you're seeing.

If you want the sort order to be alphabetical without regard to case, you will need to store a version of the name string with case normalized.  It's common to store strings to sort like this in all lowercase.  For example, instead of "AMAN SINGH", you would store "aman singh" in a special child used only for sorting.